# Best way to stitch two queries together

Tags: mysql

What is the best way to marry together this query:

```
SELECT apvr.LIMIT, apvr.APPROVER_ID, usr.IS_ACTIVE, usr.USER_FULL_NAME         
FROM APPROVERS apvr, USER usr
WHERE apvr.APPROVER_ID = usr.ID
```

and this one:

```
SELECT usr.USER_FULL_NAME, COUNT(*) as numOfApprovals, MAX(APPROVAL_DATE) as lastApprovalDate    
FROM IM_APPROVAL_DETAIL appd, USER usr
WHERE usr.ID = appd.APPROVER_ID
GROUP By usr.USER_FULL_NAME
```

?

Comment: you have to be more specific, you can use UNION or JOIN

Comment: Is `USER` one of your tables? It is a reserved keyword in `MySQL`.

Answer (score 0):

without the real data it might be a bit hard but my suggestion would be the following:

```
SELECT apvr.LIMIT, apvr.APPROVER_ID, usr.IS_ACTIVE, usr.USER_FULL_NAME, count(*) as numOfApprovals, max(appd.approval_date) as lastApprovalDate
FROM APPROVERS apvr 
JOIN USER usr ON apvr.APPROVER_ID = usr.ID
JOIN IM_APPROVAL_DETAIL appd ON usr.ID = appd.APPROVER_ID
GROUP By apvr.Approver_ID;
```

since I'm not aware of the reoccurances in those tables there might be some issues with group by clause. So the alternative would be to use a sub-select:

```
SELECT apvr.LIMIT, apvr.APPROVER_ID, usr.IS_ACTIVE, usr.USER_FULL_NAME, appd.numOfApprovals, appd.lastApprovalDate 
FROM APPROVERS apvr 
JOIN USER usr ON apvr.APPROVER_ID = usr.ID
JOIN IM_APPROVAL_DETAIL appd
JOIN (
  SELECT approver_id id, count(*) numOfApprovals, max(approval_date) lastApprovalDate 
  FROM im_approval_detail 
  GROUP by id) appd 
ON appd.id = usr.ID
```